# Why does an "authorize application" message appear only once when using doorkeeper even when clearing cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

So I setup an OAuth provider with doorkeeper on a Rails 5 app.  During the flow when a client app asks for an access token, I see a browser html page asking me to "Authorize" or "Deny" access.

Once I click "Authorize", I never see the html page asking me to Authorize/Deny again, even if I clear the cookies.  Why is this?  And how do I keep enabling the Authorize/Deny page during testing?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth authorization/authentication is stateless; it doesn't depend on cookies. Instead, the token is sent on every request that needs authentication, akin to how HTTP basic auth works.